# Not able To click in selenium browser with C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Button type is Input.

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit btn solid">
```

I want to click this Button using code, try to click on Button By ClassName.

My code is as per below but not get any success.

```
string url1 = "myUrl";
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(Application.StartupPath);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url1);    
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("wpcf7-form-control .wpcf7-submit btn solid")).Click();
```

This throws the following error :

> Compound class names not allowed. Cannot have whitespace in class name. Use CSS selectors instead. and not use single class because there is a other class with same name.

Comment: `but not get any success.` what does that mean? The form isn't submitted? The wrong button is clicked? The handler doesn't run? Are there other elements with the same class? Add an `id` or `name` to the `input` and use that instead. Check what `FindElement` returns before calling `.Click()`.

Comment: Hello, facing error :- Compound class names not allowed. Cannot have whitespace in class name. Use CSS selectors instead.
and not use single class because there is a other class with same name.

Comment: You should have posted the error in the question itself. `not succesful` is completely different from `got an error that my syntax is wrong`. You got an answer 5 minutes after you posted the error

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='submit']")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid using XPath, Instead I would add an Id to your input.
The reason being XPath is more likely to be changed over time than Id.
Also if you add another element with the same HTML, selenium will not be able to differentiate between them and will always select the first element.
Using Id also makes your code more readable.
You can try this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" Id="YourButtonId" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit btn solid">
```

And

```
 driver.FindElement(By.Id("YourButtonId")).Click();
```

Comment: Yes but there is a no Id, website is not developed by us. So we need to manage as per their code.